# Screen resizing after keyboard is shown on TextField tap

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Widget Tree - https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3MBM.png

So I have this widget tree, the TextField in question is inside the column where it shows a RenderFlex error(please ignore the error, it's only there because I animate the column to appear and disappear on button pressed).

The problem is every time I tap on the TextField my screen is pushed up from the bottom as the keyboard is pushing their way through.
To fix this issue I tried to put the Scaffold property `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false`, but it did not fix the issue.

Also when I close the keyboard, the background of my screen changes.

If you need code snippets please let me know.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: You can try wrapping top widget(Column) with SingleChildOverView for simple case

Comment: try to wrap your body of the scaffold in the singlechildscrollview.

Comment: yes, you can wrap the widget with any slider, but if you still want to push the widgets from the bottom of the keyboard, add this (MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom) to your widget as bottom padding

Answer (score 0):

i need a code snippets, but you can add SingleChildScrollView at the top of the column.

and for when you close the keyboard, the background of your screen changes, my guess for that is when the keyboard opens the screen rebuilds and this will call the build function so if you initialized any variables or anything related to the background change inside the build function it will rebuild or re-initialized.

i do not know if my answer helps but it will be better to share a code snippest, have a great day.